# Combo box with button like Visual studio " Start button"

Tags: wpf, combobox

In my project, we want a combo box with button like Visual studio " Start button".
        The button will have a down arrow . on click of that the other options will be displayed.
Each of the drop down item is a button.
Please have a look at the screenshot.

[image]

I was looking for a suitable control but could not find a exactly what I need.
Any suggestion? Any tutorial will be wonderful.
Thanks.

Comment: no pictures are attached - also please provide sample code and your attempt to the solution

Comment: @Xaphas Picture is added. I need suggestion regarding suitable control. I am not asking for a code fix. then why source code is necessary?

Comment: If you don't know what control to use, what would be your approach then? How would you try to achieve this solution? Does one of [those](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_controls.htm) do the job for you? Or would you build a [custom cuntrol](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_custom_controls.htm)? :=)

Comment: @Xaphas, I don't know for that reason I am asking for help. If I knew then why I am posting here? 
Yes, it would be a custom control. For that reason I requested for a tutorial if any one already did like that. 
No reason to inventing the same wheel again.

Comment: It's not about "reinventing the wheel". Your question implies that you haven't really done any research. [Button inside Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2740840/7759395). [Clickable Text in Combobox](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af64c03a-ac90-42ab-be25-2df11d7b0068/wpf-custom-combobox-how-to-make-the-text-part-clickable) .[Clickable Text in Combobox 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46450476/7759395).
I simply tried to push you in the right direction by asking questions that would give you an idea on how to solve the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the **RibbonSplitButton**  from the [Ribbon Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon?view=netframework-4.8). The [*RibbonSplitButton*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonsplitbutton?view=netframework-4.8) already includes the down arrow.

Here is a working example.

```
        <RibbonTab Header="Wildchild_SO">
            <RibbonGroup Header="StackOverFlow">
                <RibbonSplitButton x:Name="btnStartMain" Label="Start" SmallImageSource="Images/add64px.png">
                    <RibbonMenuItem x:Name="btnStart" Click="btnStart_Click" Header="Start Test" ImageSource="Images/add64px.png"/>
                    <RibbonMenuItem x:Name="btnStop" Click="btnStop_Click" Header="Stop Test" ImageSource="Images/cross64px.png" />
                </RibbonSplitButton>
            </RibbonGroup>
        </RibbonTab>
```

[image: Ribbon Menu]

Comment: Glad I could help you out. Cheers bro! If you think it is the correct answer - do accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjFy7.png)

```
<Button Background="GhostWhite">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <Viewbox Width="20" Height="20">
  <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
    <Path Data="M8,5.14V19.14L19,12.14L8,5.14Z" Fill="Green" />
  </Canvas>
 </Viewbox>
 <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="MyButton"/>
 <Viewbox Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20">
   <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
     <Path Data="M7,10L12,15L17,10H7Z" Fill="Black" />
   </Canvas>
 </Viewbox>
```